# How to see all rows of skimr output without changing its layout, in console as well as in latex pdf output?

Tags: r, latex, skimr

I used skimr package for descriptive table. On using View() function it is showing a very-very long table, 600 rows.

[image: skimr console output]

[image: long table]

[image: session info]

Comment: does this helps  ? options(tibble.print_max = Inf). Use longtable argument in xtable to produce a table spanning several pages.

Answer (score 1):

Skimr was just released on CRAN and the new version has a function`skim_to_list` and one `skim_to_wide` that give you the results in two different wide versions. Use these instead of `skim()` e.g. `skim_to_wide(iris)`.

What you are seeing is the default skim object. Another option you have is to use dplyr or other approach to put the data into the format you want.

Comment: FYI, you apply the `skim_to_wide()` function directly to your dataset, not the object created by `skim()`.